# "unsupported initializer for address space" in Opencl on Linux Mint

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

I get the following Error when i try to run the following pyopencl code on my linxu mint computer with a Radeon grafic card.

> unsupported initializer for address space in wordpuzzle

The program is easy to understand: I have a INT Array which i copy to kernel. I read out the first number of the INT Array and based on the returned number i want to pick the char from the CharSSet and return it.

When i replace

> wordbuff[0] = charSSet[**a_g[0]**];

with

> wordbuff[0] = charSSet[**10**];

then it works well! 
WHY???

el Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

a_np = np.array([10,22,5,3,8])


ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

mf = cl.mem_flags
a_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a_np)



wordValue = np.array(['\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'])
word_buffer = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=wordValue)


prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void wordpuzzle(
    __global const int *a_g, __global unsigned char *wordbuff)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0); 
    char charSSet[53] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    if (gid == 0){
        wordbuff[0] = charSSet[a_g[0]]; 
    }

}
""").build()

res_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, a_np.nbytes)

prg.wordpuzzle(queue, (1,), (1,), a_g, word_buffer)

theChars = np.empty_like(wordValue)
cl.enqueue_read_buffer(queue,word_buffer,theChars)

print(theChars)
```

THE WHOLE ERROR REPORT:

> Choose platform: [0] 
>   Choice [0]: Set the environment variable PYOPENCL_CTX='' to avoid
>   being asked again. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "demo.py", line 35, in 
>       """).build()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/**init**.py", line 213, in
>   build
>       options=options, source=self._source)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/**init**.py", line 253, in
>   _build_and_catch_errors
>       raise err pyopencl.RuntimeError: clBuildProgram failed: build program failure -
>
> Build on :
>
> unsupported initializer for address space in wordpuzzle (options: -I
>   /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/cl) (source saved as
>   /tmp/tmp7PxezZ.cl)

Comment: This works fine for me on nvidia gpu and intel cpu on Windows and I can't see why it shouldn't work. Maybe try updating your opencl drivers or graphic card drivers?

Comment: Hey thank you for your time but everything is up to date. Do you have a linux system where you can try it? On my mac it is working too...but not on this linux mint machine :

Comment: Yep. Ubuntu 14.04 + amd gpu is working fine too.